# High Availability with the Supermicro SMC2208 (MegaRAID)

Tags: high-availability, supermicro, megaraid

I haven't been able to find a solid answer in the documentation, nor from the vendor since this model is out of production.

We have a `Supermicro SMC2208` 24-drive-bay RAID.

I would like to create a highly available environment with this existing hardware - mostly in the event of an OS failure on the SMC2208's two mirrored OS disks.

Is it possible to:

1. Use a second Supermicro SMC2208 24-bay controller so that (in normal operation) each SMC2208 serves its own 24 bays, but if one of the controllers had an operating system failure, the other controller could serve it's own 24 bays, and see/serve  the other RAID controllers 24 bays (as if it were external enclosure)?
2. Is it possible to do roughly the same as #1 just using a server (not another integrated RAID controller)? I.e. If the RAID controller's OS failed, the server would see that the OS on the Supermicro SMC2208 failed, and take over serving the RAID controller's disks?

Comment: No, this is not possible without very specialized hardware. You would basically need two complete servers in one case, every one with it's own CPU, memory and all components that are attached to this (this exists).

Comment: 2 complete servers might be an option. If I'm understanding correctly, basically we would not use the OS that lives on the SMC2208 - but just use it as a RAID drive enclosure? And then have two separate servers that work as the access points (in an HA)? Is there possibly a link or document that describes this?